# Finding the maximum XOR metric

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, binary

I'm trying to find a way to find n keys (x bits) where the XOR distance metric between them would be greatest.

By XOR distance metric I just mean the value when two keys are XORed together.

So for example, given a 10 bit key, find 10 keys which have the greatest distance between them in terms of the XOR distance metric.

Comment: You want to maximize the distance between 10 objects. Means that you want to maximize $C_{10}^2 = 45$ numbers. You can't maximize 45 numbers at the same time. You can only maximize one number. So you have to choose if you want to maximize the maximum of these numbers, or their mean value (arithmetic, geometric ...)

Comment: Could you explain why its 2 Choose 10?

Comment: Distance is defined between 2 objects. There are 10 objects. So there are $C_{10}^2$ distances you can compute.